# Simplify terms within an expression

Tags: sympy, simplify

`Sympy` can simplify this:

```
In [26]: (asinh(sinh(x))).simplify()
Out[26]: x
```

but doesn't simplify that:

```
In [28]: (asinh(sinh(x))+1).simplify()
Out[28]: asinh(sinh(x)) + 1
```

How can I ask for subparts of an expression to be simplified? If possible, I'd like to avoid equation-scale simplification, e.g. that a common denominator is found and factorised out for all terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguably, this simplification should not happen at all because it's not always true: for example, `asinh(sinh(2*I))` is not `2*I`.  The current implementation of `simplify` has a clause for "canceling" a function and its inverse, which only applies if the entire expression is that function, and does not pay attention to things like `asin(sin(pi))` being `0` rather than `pi`. Inverses are tricky.

But the following approach, based on `replace`, will replace all known "function-inverse" pairs:

```
expr = sqrt(asinh(sinh(x))) + sin(asin(exp(2*x+1)))
expr = expr.replace(lambda f: isinstance(f, Function) and isinstance(f.args[0], f.inverse(argindex=1)), lambda f: f.args[0].args[0])
# expr is now sqrt(x) + exp(2*x + 1)
```

The first argument of `replace` is a filter function,

```
lambda f: isinstance(f, Function) and isinstance(f.args[0], f.inverse(argindex=1))
```

which asserts that f is a Function whose first argument  is its inverse.

The second argument of `replace` is the action to be done on matching subexpression,

```
lambda f: f.args[0].args[0]
```

means: replace by the argument of the argument, i.e., `asinh(sinh(x)) -> x`.

As noted above, it's not guaranteed that the result of such "simplification" is mathematically equivalent to the original expression.